# Deploy laravel app to shared host with npm dependencies

Tags: laravel, npm, composer-php

I am about to finally deploy my laravel app to shared host soon, using ssh. My question here is: in local enviroment I installed all npm dependencies (npm install), to compile all vue.js scripts.

What i already know is that: after uploading everything to shared host I should run "composer install" to install composer dependencies and edit .env.

But should I also run "npm install" if I already have my app.js compiled on local enviroment?

Thanks,
PS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually probably don't have npm on a shared server.  At least with HostGator, which is where I have experience, it wasn't possible - in which case - you would need to run and compile `npm` locally before pushing to the server.

Comment: Alright, so I guess that compiling app.js locally is enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per my experience with Hostinger it is not possible to install NODE, and NPM via a command on the server. Because it is not a private server and it is already given us our requirements setup during server selection. So you can do this by pushing your js assets with git and pulling on the server to get js.

Comment: You are right in shared hosting we can not add packages manually.